# Problemas con comando getLineNumber en Android Studio para Android 9.0

Tags: android

Necesito comando getLineNumber para obtener el numero de teléfono de la SIM, IMEI e IMSI en Android Studio 3.2 para versiones de Android 9.0 y 8.0. No se si se necesitan permisos especiales.

Me funciona en Android Studio hasta Android version 6.0 pero no superior.

Comment: Hola Carlos, nuevamente te sugerimos añadir lo que has tratado para saber que método tratas de realizar, también puedes incluir lo que has investigado, edita tu pregunta en base a [ask], saludos.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Efectivamente no te va a funcionar ya que a partir de la versión 6 (Android Marshmallow) tienes que solicitar al usuario que introduzca los permisos manualmente.

Te dejo este enlace a la documentación oficial de cómo [solicitar permisos Android](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting?hl=es-419)

Espero que te sirva, si no lo consigues puedo escribirte el código que necesitar para obtener los permisos del usuario

Un saludo